# How to determine my OutputStream internally buffered

Tags: java, stream

`OutputStream` is an abstract class that contains a `flush()` method that per the javadoc does nothing. I know that the flush() method is used to push out anything that is kept in internal buffers. I know that I need to use flush() if I want to make sure everything I've written to the stream that *might* be held in an internal buffer get sent out.

The key is this *might*. How do I know if the stream I receive from an API is doing internal buffering or not? What if the javadoc of the api does not mention explicitly if internal buffering is occurring and hence flush() is recommended? If I'm using an API that returns an `OutputStream` and I write bytes to this and I want to make sure they are sent, it seems like a waste to call flush() on the basis of "just in case it actually does have an internal buffer".

Comment: Just call `flush()`. No need to tie yourself into knots about whether it will do anything. If it did, it was necessary: if not, not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to determine my OutputStream internally buffered

In general, there isn't a reliable way to do it.  Period.

If you know *a priori* the set of **all possible** stream classes that can be used in a code-base, then **in some cases** you can tell; e.g. based on clunky `instanceof` tests.  But even that is fragile.

> ... it seems like a waste to call `flush()` on a non-buffered stream.

The good news is that calling `flush` on a stream that is not buffered is going to be very cheap ... or even free.

For example, `OutputStream::flush()` is an empty method.  Any output stream class that doesn't explicitly override it (e.g. `FileOutputStream`),  will similarly have a no-op implementation of `flush`.  If the JIT compiler is able to inline the call to a no-op `flush` method, it will be optimized away entirely.

Comment: I think it's bad practice to clutter my code with statements on the basis of "welp maybe we need it or not who can say??? let's write it just to be sure". The point of my question is to get away from that and to be deliberate when flushing.

Comment: I say it is bad practice to clutter your code with tests to see if you should call `flush()` or not when it actually makes zero difference to performance.  That is the point of my answer!  (And besides, the `if` tests are likely to be harder for the JIT compiler to optimize away.) Obviously, there is no point in calling flush twice in short succession, but that is *orthogonal* to the issue of buffering.

Comment: @Mishax You can't seriously be suggesting that four lines of code is better than one.

Comment: Stay on topic please, the question is "how to determine my outputstream is internally buffered". I am looking for answers to this specific question. I am not looking to start a debate with either of you if you think I'm right for wanting to determine this or not.

Comment: OK.  I have answered that too.

Comment: @EJP thinks it is possible to do it in four lines of code though, what is that about?

Comment: I think he is talking about the *hypothetical* case where you could determine this.  And the clunky "if it is buffered then flush" code that you would need to write to do conditional flushing.  (And that's what I was referring to too.)

Comment: @Mishax: the simplest solution is to never call `flush()` at all, but ensure to `close` the stream properly when you’re done, as you should do anyway. `close` is guaranteed to flush all pending data and that’s all you need. And, just like `flush()` does nothing for unbuffered streams, all buffered streams will regularly flush automatically, i.e. every time their internal buffer is full. So instead of trying to find out when flush is definitely unneeded, you should ask yourself why you think, manual flushing was needed at one point.

Comment: Well, yea, but what about the case where the stream is half of a socket that you are using to talk to a remote server using a request-response protocol.  Or the case where you are writing messages to a log file. Flushes are sometimes necessary.  My advice: if the use-case needs flushes, just call `flush()` and don't worry about the tiny wastage that might be incurred if the stream is unbuffered.

Comment: OTOH ... calling flush *too often* on a buffered stream is bad for other reasons.  (And, BTW, a buffered stream only flushes regularly if you write to it regularly.  If you stop writing ... no flushes.)